# in django data base stored image not display in application and i have no error while running the code

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have no error while run the code the images will stored database but it will not display in webpage ,I post my source code here
**my application page code**

{% extends 'shop/layouts/main.html' %}

{% block title %}
registration | onlineshopping
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

```
<section class="py-5 text-center container" style="margin-top: 70px;">
    <div class="row py-lg-5">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="fw-light">Bestsellers</h1>
        <p class="lead text-muted">Our most popular products based on sales.updated honourly</p>
        <p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Already User</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">Register</a>
        </p>
    </div>    
    </div>
</section>

    <section class="bg-light py-4 my-5">
     <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">
        <h4 class="mb-3">Categories</h4>
        <hr style="border-color:#b8bfc2">
    </div>

    {% for item in category %}
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card my-3">
            <img src="{{item.image.url}}" class="card-image-top" alt="Categories">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-primary">{{item.name}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ item.description }}</p>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View Details</a>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

</div>
</div>
    </section>
```

{% endblock content %}

**models.pycode**

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
import os

def getFileName(request,filename):
    now_time=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S")
    new_filename="%s%s"%(now_time,filename)
    return os.path.join('uploads/',new_filename)

# Create your models here.
class Catagory(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=150,null=False,blank=False)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=getFileName,null=True,blank=True)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=False)
    status=models.BooleanField(default=False,help_text="0-show,1-Hidden")
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    catagory=models.ForeignKey(Catagory,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=150,null=False,blank=False)
    vendor=models.CharField(max_length=150,null=False,blank=False)
    product_image=models.ImageField(upload_to=getFileName,null=True,blank=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    original_price=models.FloatField(null=False,blank=False)
    selling_price=models.FloatField(null=False,blank=False)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=False)
    status=models.BooleanField(default=False,help_text="0-show,1-Hidden")
    trending=models.BooleanField(default=False,help_text="0-default,1-Trending")
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name
```

**setting.py file**

```
"""
Django settings for karthi_django project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-83vl+-z)2vz9+u*=a#%00v2^%i6^v^rg-*#_!=@nqvezk=4^)-"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jazzmin',
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "shop"
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "karthi_django.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "karthi_django.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"
MEDIA_URL = "/images/"
MEDIA_ROOT = (BASE_DIR,"images")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

**url.py**

```
"""karthi_django URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('',include("shop.urls")),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import *

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, "shop/index.html")


    
def register(request):
    return render(request, "shop/register.html")



def collections(request):
    catagory=Catagory.objects.filter(status=0)
    return render(request,'shop/collections.html',{"catagory":catagory})
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from.models import * 


admin.site.register(Catagory)
admin.site.register(Product)
```

Comment: Kind of silly, But try putting  `MEDIA_ROOT = (BASE_DIR,"images\")` instead of `MEDIA_ROOT = (BASE_DIR,"images")` in **settings.py**

Answer (score 0):

MEDIA_URL = "images/"

remove the start slash from your MEDIA_URL.

Answer (score 0):

in html file, replace thr src for images to {{item.img.url}} instead of {{item.image.url}}.

image needs to be replaced by img.